# StdOutput redirection only partly succeeding

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, stdout, named-pipes

I have a console application who's output I'd like to capture. I'm partially succeeding. Most messages are being captured. But some are still ending up on the console window, and are bypassing my capture.

This is the code I'm using to read the output:

```
_hProcess = new Process();

_hProcess.StartInfo.FileName = _Filename;  // "bochsdbg.exe"
_hProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;  // "-q"
_hProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_Filename);

_hProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

_hProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_hProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

_hProcess.OutputDataReceived += (Sender, Data) => _Buffer += Data.Data + "\n";

_hProcess.Start();

_hProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

_ProcessStdInput = _hProcess.StandardInput;

_Reporters.Call("Info", "Process " + _Filename + " is started");
```

I'm on windows 8, this is not a program meant to go in production but a tool I'm going to use. I'm on framework version 4.5.

What I've tried:

I tried to open the console in a batch file and redirect the input like this:

> cmd.exe bochsdbg.exe > output.txt

This captures the same text as my own application does, which leads me to believe there's something else going on. Does anyone know how I can capture the rest of the consoles output?

If that isn't an option, does anybody know what API's Microsoft exposes for printing to console display memory? I can't find anything on this.

Fixed code:

```
_hProcess = new Process();

_hProcess.StartInfo.FileName = _Filename;  // "bochs.exe"
_hProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;  // "-q"
_hProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_Filename);

_hProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

_hProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
_hProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
_hProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

_hProcess.OutputDataReceived += (Sender, Data) => _Buffer += Data.Data + "\n";
_hProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (Sender, Data) => _Buffer += Data.Data + "\n";

_hProcess.Start();

_hProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
_hProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

_ProcessStdInput = _hProcess.StandardInput;

_Reporters.Call("Info", "Process " + _Filename + " is started");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra output you're seeing is probably actually `stderr`, or `StandardError` in .NET terms. If you change your command line to `cmd.exe bochsdbg.exe > output.txt 2> error.txt`, you'll capture both.

Similarly, in your .NET code, you can use the [RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx) property.

Comment: Ughh, what a mess. It appears you're right. With that batch command I capture all the data. It's very strange it seems to print parts of it's normal output messages as errors :-/. This program must be full of spaghetti-code under the hood. Many thanks for your quick answer though, I was stuck on this for a few hours. Edit: Must wait before accepting (who came up with that? A right answer is a right answer...)